# Find the lowest unused number

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I've setup a std map to map some numbers, at this point I know what numbers I'm mapping from an to, eg:

```
std::map<int, int> myMap;

map[1] = 2;
map[2] = 4;
map[3] = 6;
```

Later however, I want to map some numbers to the lowest number possilbe that is not in the map, eg:

```
map[4] = getLowestFreeNumberToMapTo(map); // I'd like this to return 1
map[5] = getLowestFreeNumberToMapTo(map); // I'd like this to return 3
```

Any easy way of doing this?

I considered building an ordered list of numbers as I added them to the map so I could just look for 1, not find it, use it, add it etc.

Comment: I'd expect the lowest values to be INT_MIN and INT_MIN+1 ? And if it was a map<int, unsigned< I'd still expect UINT_MIN==0

Answer (score 7):

Something like

```
typedef std::set<int> SetType;
SetType used;           // The already used numbers
int freeCounter = 1;    // The first available free number

void AddToMap(int i)
{
    used.insert(i);
    // Actually add the value to map
}

void GetNewNumber()
{
    SetType::iterator iter = used.lower_bound(freeCounter);
    while (iter != used.end() && *iter == freeCounter)
    {
        ++iter;
        ++freeCounter;
    }
    return freeCounter++;
}
```

If your map is quite big but sparse, this will work like o(log(N)), where N is the number of items in the map - in most cases you won't have to iterate through the set, or just make a few steps.
Otherwise, if there are few gaps in the map, then you would better have a set of free items in the range [1..maxValueInTheMap].

Comment: This is a better algorithm than it seems at first sight. Note that although *some* calls to GetNewNumber() might take many steps, the *total* number of times freeCounter is incremented (and hence the total running time of GetNewNumber(), divided by the logarithmic factor for set operations) is bounded by the number of items assigned in the map (since if you've assigned N numbers, freeCounter ≤ N+1). So if you've assigned up to map[N], all the calls to GetNewNumber() so far will have taken only O(N log N) time: GetNewNumber is O(log N) amortised. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis

Comment: (In other words, the algorithm works well even when the map is not sparse; it is always O(log N) amortised.)

Comment: The GetNewNumber() is the common missing item searching based on index-value coordinataion, but I still can understand why you guys said this is an o(logN) function.

Answer (score 4):

Finding the lowest unused number is a very common operation in UNIX kernels, as every `open`/`socket`/etc. syscall is supposed to bind to the lowest unused FD number.

On Linux, the algorithm in [`fs/file.c`­#`alloc_fd`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=fs/file.c;hb=HEAD) is:

- keep track of `next_fd`, a low water mark -- it is not necessarily 100% accurate
- whenever a FD is freed, `next_fd = min(fd, next_fd)`
- to allocate a FD, start searching the bitmap starting from `next_fd` -- [`lib/find_next_bit.c`­#`find_next_zero_bit`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=lib/find_next_bit.c;hb=HEAD) is linear but still very fast, because it takes `BITS_PER_LONG` strides at a time
- after a FD is allocated, `next_fd = fd + 1`

FreeBSD's [`sys/kern/kern_descrip.c`­#`fdalloc`](http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/kern_descrip.c) follows the same idea: start with `int fd_freefile; /* approx. next free file */`, and search the bitmap upwards.

---

However, these are all operating under the assumption that *most* processes have few FDs open, and very, very few have thousands.  If the numbers will go much higher, with sparse holes, the common solution (as far as I've seen) is

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int high_water_mark = 0;
vector<int> unused_numbers = vector<int>();

int get_new_number() {
    if (used_numbers.empty())
        return high_water_mark++;
    pop_heap(unused_numbers.begin(), unused_numbers.end(), greater<int>());
    return unused_numbers.pop_back();
}

void recycle_number(int number) {
    unused_numbers.push_back(number);
    push_heap(unused_numbers.begin(), unused_numbers.end(), greater<int>());
}
```

(untested code... idea is: keep a high water mark; try to steal from `unused` below the high water mark, or up the high water mark otherwise; return freed to `unused`)

and if your assumption is that the *used* numbers will be sparse, then Dmitry's solution makes more sense.

Comment: As I pointed out in the comment to the other answer, the other solution does not actually require the used numbers to be sparse (to be good upto log factors, at least.) This answer is interesting: the question seems to only have inserts, no deletes, and potentially arbitrarily high numbers assigned, but yours is with both inserts and deletes, and the total "range" being small enough that it is possible to keep a list of unused numbers.

Comment: I mention "sparse" because if you only have 5 unused numbers at a time, O(5) is nice and small, but if half of them are unused, O(log n) is (relatively) a lot bigger.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a bidirectional map class for this problem. That way you can simply check if value 1 exists etc.

**Edit**

The benefits of using a bimap is that there already exist robust implementations of it and even if searching for the next free number is O(n) it is only an issue if n is large (or possibly if n is moderate and this is called very frequently). Overall making for a simple implementation that is unlikely to be error prone and easily maintainable.

If *n* is large or this operation is performed very frequently than investing the effort of implementing a more advanced solution is merited. IMHO.

Comment: this hides the algorithm... which is the Q. Which algo is used to search the keyed items on that class?

Comment: Checking if value n exists to find lowest available sounds like an O(n) exercise